# .exe file wont run from Task Scheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have an .exe file that i scheduled to run from the Task Scheduler.
The schedule works fine and the .exe file does what it needs to do.
In the settings of the task, I configured as follows :
**"If the task is already running, then the following rule applies : Stop the Existing instance"**
So basically if the last instance of the schedule did not finish, it will terminate it and run the next instance. I decided to change this setting because of problems that occur with it.

I changed it to
**"If the task is already running, then the following rule applies : Do not start a new instance"**

**The Problem :**
After I changed this setting,  the task wont run anymore, not even manually when I try to "Run" it.
The setting above is the only thing I changed.

When I try to run it, I get the following error :** Action failed to start - Launch Failure ( 0x80070005)**

Because of this, I tried to run the .exe through .bat script but it creates another set of problems

Any idea why I cant seem to be able to run the .exe file from the scheduler? What may cause the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `0x80070005` means `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - under what account is the task scheduled to run and does it have access to the path where the executable is?

Comment: @Remko, yes, it has access to the path of the .exe.
the task runs fine with all the settings and the same user with the setting :
If the task is already running, then the following rule applies : Stop the Existing instance.
when i changed it to Do not start a new instance, it stopped running

Comment: can you share screenshots ?